# How to bind Backbone model to jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone along with jQuery and jqGrid and encountering problem with binding the backbone collection with jqGrid.

This is the Response I get from Server:

```
{"DogModel":[
    {"name":"Jane","breed":"Great Dane"},
    {"name":"Rocky","breed":"golden Retriver"},
    {"name":"Jim","breed":"Lab"}
]}
```

In View, I get the data like

```
[{"name":"Jane","breed":"Great Dane"},
{"name":"Rocky","breed":"golden Retriver"},
{"name":"Jim","breed":"Lab"}]
```

//jqGgrid code in view

```
jQuery("#dogsList").jqGrid({ 
    datatype: 'json',
    data:this.collection.models.toJSON(),
    width:'100%',
    colNames:['name', 'breed'], 
    colModel:[  
        {name:'name', align:'left'},
        {name:'breed', align:'left'}
    ],
    loadComplete : function(data) {
        alert('grid loading completed ' + data);
    },
    loadError : function(xhr, status, error)  {
        alert('grid loading error' + error);
    }
});
```

I tried replacing  `data:this.collection.models.toJSON()`, with `data:this.collection.models[0].toJSON()` and `data:this.collection.toJSON()`, it throws unexpected character parse error.

What is that I need to do to bind the model to jqGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know perfectly jqGrid but I look their examples and I found a solution to add the models on your grid.

**You need to change your `datatype` to `local` and add manually each row on your jqGrid.**

The best thing is to see the code work on jsFiddle and learn how the code works : http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/qM98D/

Comment: Thanks Atinux. Changing datatype to local works. But have done few tweaks along with it. Used the same response from the server(i.e, I didn't return res.DogModel from parse but rather returned res as it is). Setting data:Dogs.models[0].get('dogModel'), does the trick.

Comment: You don't want to use addRowData for large datasets.

Comment: but this doesn't explain how the row will re-render whenever a model is changed!, I guess we need to write that logic along with this.

Comment: I think JQGrid would need a special plugin to accomodate this behavior. In the meantime I would recommend putting hooks into the Backbone Model and Collection fetch success() methods

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
datatype: 'local',
data:this.collection.toJSON()
```

This works for me.