# Backbone: Getting data from server into JQGrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, backbone.js

I have a Web Application that currently uses JQGrid but I'm trying to introduce Backbone.js to improve code organization. What I'm trying to do is get data from the server using a Collection, and then add the JSON information to my defined JQGrid but I can't get it to work. My JQGrid is defined like this:

```
var tareasHumanasTable = $("#grillaTH").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        height: 'auto',
        colNames:[ colNames...],
        colModel:[ colModel...]
}
```

And my Model and Collection are defined like this:

```
window.TareaHumana = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.TareaHumanaCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:  TareaHumana,
    url: "bandejaTareas/buscarTH"
});
```

I have a button that when clicked starts server communication. Now is doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#botonBuscar").bind('click',function(){
        var tareaHumanaList = new TareaHumanaCollection();
        tareaHumanaList.fetch({data: $("#formBandejaTareas").serializeObject()});
        //alert("tareaHumanaList.toJSON(): " + tareaHumanaList.toJSON());
        tareaHumanaList.each(function(tareaHumana, i){
            //alert("tareaHumana.toJSON(): " + tareaHumana.toJSON());
            tareasHumanasTable.jqGrid('addRowData', (i + 1), tareaHumana.toJSON());
        });
```

That code doesn't work at all. With Firebug I verified that the server sends the data in the correct format but the code isn't working. The weirdest thing is that when I uncomment the "alert(...)" lines everything starts to work.

Comment: You posted almost no jqGrid code and no test JSON data. I don't use backbone myself, but the part of jqGrid usage which you posted is very uneffective. `addRowData` is the slowest way to fill the grid. Because you don't fill it at all the problem can be in the data from `tareaHumana.toJSON()`. The data have to corresponds the `colModel` of the grid, but as I wrote before the usage of `addRowData` in loop is really bad idea. You should better describe how you have to fill the grid. In any way some examples of JSON response and `colModel` are really required.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with JSON parsing, it involved only asynchronous fetching from Backbone. On the Grid population, I followed this recommendation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646622/how-to-bind-backbone-model-to-jqgrid. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: The usage of `addowData` is vary bad especially. I would change the demo which you reference as [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/qM98D/67/). It's important to create grid *with data* If you create grid and then add 100 rows, then you will see that at inserting of *one* row or with changing *one* element on the page, the position of *all existing elements will be recalculated*. By creating grid with `gridview: true, data: mydata` you can create the grid with full body content as one operation. The more rows you have the more will be seen the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that `fetch` is asynchronous. So if you immediately call `each` after `fetch` it's probably your collection won't be populated. You should use `success` callback. For example take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048665/1248256).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use datatype:jsonstring and create a format function on the collection to provide corect data format to jqgrid.